# Get an element of an array only once

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with 4 colors.

EX:

```
var c1 = getColor();
var c2 = getColor();
var c3 = getColor();
var c4 = getColor();

function geraColor()
{
    var colors = ['#3498db', '#8e44ad', '#e67e22', '#1abc9c'];
    //Return each value only once
}
```

I have a list of Teachers, each teacher has a sublist with his disciplines.
Like this:  [Professor and Disciplines](http://codepen.io/Ghaleon/pen/ZOXrRV)

Each time I Click on a Professor, everytime I click on a professor's name, I add those disciplines inside my calendar (Alreay Done).

What I need help with is:  I need to generate a unique color (random or not) to each professor I click/expand.

Obs: I have a limit of 4 professors, so I need to generate only 4 colors.
Obs2: Everytime I click again on a professor, closing his disciplines. I need to make that color he was using avaliable again.

Comment: **I'd like to ALWAYS get an element only once.** is it the requirement?

Comment: I can't get the same color to different professor. But once I close his disciplines, that color must be avaliable again.  (I'd like to ask for a comment explaining the downvote).

Comment: What about simply setting your `colors` array in the global scope and using `pickedColor = colors.pop()` / `colors.push(releasedColor)`?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the `colors` array should be a pool of values, such that calling `getColor()` removes one of the values from the pool and returns it to be added to a professor, and then closing the professor's disciplines adds that professor's color back to the pool.

Answer (score 1):

AFA I understood your question, maybe this is what you want to achieve :

```js
var colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "orange", "blue", "pink"];
var defaultColor = "black";

function getRndColor() {
  var size = colors.length;
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
  return colors.splice(rnd, 1)[0];
}

function getColor(elem) {
  var color = defaultColor;
  if (elem.checked) {
    color = getRndColor();
  } else {
    colors.push(elem.parentElement.style.color);
  }
  elem.parentElement.style.color = color;
  console.log(colors);
}
```

```html
<span><input type="checkbox" onclick="getColor(this)"/>Get Random Color</span>

<span><input type="checkbox" onclick="getColor(this)"/>Get Random Color</span>
<br/>
<span><input type="checkbox" onclick="getColor(this)"/>Get Random Color</span>

<span><input type="checkbox" onclick="getColor(this)"/>Get Random Color</span>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just manage a dictionnary remembrering professor's color :

```js
var profColors = {};

function getColor(profName){ //profId would be better
  if (!profColors[profName])
    profColors[profName] = getRandomColor(); // or nor random...
  
  return profColors[profName];
}
```

However, not sure I understand what you want to achieve...

Comment: Like google calendar, but the disciplines that I insert in the calendar (events) has to be the same color for each professor. With a Max count of 4 professors at once, so 4 colors at same time.